# The IOS app built with flutter cannot connect to the network after being downloaded from the App Store

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter

When I use flutter to build and upload to the App Store, some users may not be able to connect to the network after downloading the software
I'm using the Dio package, and I've turned on the permission to allow the network, and I'm using https requests.

Please let me know if you have a solution, thanks!